# Power Bi Workspace activity monitoring

Tags: powerbi, workspace

I was wondering if there was a way on a enterprise level to view.... power bi workspace activity? For example has the workspace been updated or opened in x amount of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are log files you can explore.

[From the documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-auditing)

Knowing who is taking what action on which item in your Power BI tenant can be critical in helping your organization fulfil its requirements, like meeting regulatory compliance and records management. With Power BI, you have two options to track user activity: The Power BI activity log and the unified audit log. These logs both contain a complete copy of the Power BI auditing data, but there are several key differences, as summarized in the following table.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Comment: No problem @Joey